# Html/css position inner ul to outer ul

Tags: html, css, position, html-lists

I'm having some trouble with html/css positioning in what is some sort of a menu.
I have a ul element with a number of child li elements. Each of these li elements contains another ul element. So for example there is something like this:

```
<ul class="level0">
<li id="nav-1-1" class="level1"><span> Option1 </span>
<ul id="submenu" class="">
    <li class="level2" first="" nav-2-2="">
    <li class="level2" first="" nav-2-2="">
    <li class="level2" first="" nav-2-2="">
</ul>
</li>
<li id="nav-1-1" class="level1"><span> Option2 </span>
<ul id="submenu" class="">
    <li class="level2" first="" nav-2-2="">
    <li class="level2" first="" nav-2-2="">
    <li class="level2" first="" nav-2-2="">
</ul>
</li>
```

This is just an example.
What I would like is to position the inner ul element to the outer, and not the li. How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you say you don't want to position it to it's ancestor, do you mean you want to position it absolute to the outer ul element? or something else?

Comment: I haven't been quite precise, have to say.
The thing is that the outer ul has several list elements which are items in a menu. Each of these li elements has inner ul as a sub-menu. What I want is all of these sub-menus fixed to a certain position, ie. top right corner of the outer ul. Hope this clarifies things a bit?

Answer (score 1):

make the outer ul `position: relative;` and then the inner ul `position: absolute;` 
 then you can position it whereever you want to according to the outer ul.
still don't really see the point in this as you can position it absolute also to the parent li elemennt.

Comment: The problem is that I want all the inner ul elements, which are sub-menus, positioned in the same position.

Comment: I think what @stratton means is to make `ul.level0` `position:absolute`, then set `ul#submenu` to `position:relative`. This will make all of your submenus start from the same positioning origin.